# Convert nested json to flat dataframe in R

Tags: json, r, dataframe

My `JSON` struture looks like this:

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=5e56a90d32df774fa2beaf69bdb9f0af

I want it converted to a completely flat `dataframe`.

```
res <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data, simplifyDataFrame=TRUE)
```

or

```
  res <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data, flatten=TRUE)
```

give weird results.

I have heard of ndjson but it throws incompatible gcc error in ubuntu 14.04.

Is there a robust way to do it? I have tried stream_in from `jsonlite` too but it gives weird results as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are build instructions for `ndjson` on the github page and if you look at the `INSTALL` file. However, you don't have `ndjson`, you have a JSON array of complex JSON objects which are easily handled by `jsonlite`:

Data:

```
txt <- '[
  {
    "agent": {
      "active_since": null,
      "available": false,
      "created_at": "2016-09-29T14:47:00+05:30",
      "id": 1000124609,
      "last_active_at": null,
      "occasional": false,
      "points": 100,
      "scoreboard_level_id": 1000316008,
      "signature": null,
      "signature_html": "<div dir=\\"ltr\\">\\n<p><br></p>\\r\\n</div>",
      "ticket_permission": 1,
      "updated_at": "2016-09-30T17:57:59+05:30",
      "user_id": 1013512877,
      "user": {
        "active": false,
        "address": null,
        "created_at": "2015-06-29T11:51:04+05:30",
        "deleted": false,
        "description": null,
        "email": "aakash.r@stalkbuylove.com",
        "external_id": null,
        "fb_profile_id": null,
        "helpdesk_agent": true,
        "id": 1013512877,
        "job_title": "",
        "language": "en",
        "mobile": null,
        "name": "Aakash Rathore",
        "phone": null,
        "time_zone": "New Delhi",
        "twitter_id": null,
        "updated_at": "2016-09-29T14:47:23+05:30"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "agent": {
      "active_since": null,
      "available": false,
      "created_at": "2016-09-29T14:48:34+05:30",
      "id": 1000124610,
      "last_active_at": null,
      "occasional": false,
      "points": 100,
      "scoreboard_level_id": 1000316008,
      "signature": null,
      "signature_html": "<div dir=\\"ltr\\">\\n<p><br></p>\\r\\n</div>",
      "ticket_permission": 1,
      "updated_at": "2016-09-30T18:02:30+05:30",
      "user_id": 1021869364,
      "user": {
        "active": false,
        "address": null,
        "created_at": "2016-08-09T15:18:06+05:30",
        "deleted": false,
        "description": null,
        "email": "abhinav.a@stalkbuylove.com",
        "external_id": null,
        "fb_profile_id": null,
        "helpdesk_agent": true,
        "id": 1021869364,
        "job_title": "",
        "language": "en",
        "mobile": null,
        "name": "Abhinav Anand",
        "phone": null,
        "time_zone": "New Delhi",
        "twitter_id": null,
        "updated_at": "2016-09-29T14:48:52+05:30"
      }
    }
  }
]'
```

Code:

```
library(jsonlite)

dplyr::glimpse(fromJSON(txt, flatten=TRUE))
##     Observations: 2
## Variables: 31
## $ agent.active_since        <lgl> NA, NA
## $ agent.available           <lgl> FALSE, FALSE
## $ agent.created_at          <chr> "2016-09-29T14:47:00+05:30", "2016-09-29T14:48:34+05:30"
## $ agent.id                  <int> 1000124609, 1000124610
## $ agent.last_active_at      <lgl> NA, NA
## $ agent.occasional          <lgl> FALSE, FALSE
## $ agent.points              <int> 100, 100
## $ agent.scoreboard_level_id <int> 1000316008, 1000316008
## $ agent.signature           <lgl> NA, NA
## $ agent.signature_html      <chr> "<div dir=\"ltr\">\n<p><br></p>\r\n</div>", "<div dir=\"ltr\...
## $ agent.ticket_permission   <int> 1, 1
## $ agent.updated_at          <chr> "2016-09-30T17:57:59+05:30", "2016-09-30T18:02:30+05:30"
## $ agent.user_id             <int> 1013512877, 1021869364
## $ agent.user.active         <lgl> FALSE, FALSE
## $ agent.user.address        <lgl> NA, NA
## $ agent.user.created_at     <chr> "2015-06-29T11:51:04+05:30", "2016-08-09T15:18:06+05:30"
## $ agent.user.deleted        <lgl> FALSE, FALSE
## $ agent.user.description    <lgl> NA, NA
## $ agent.user.email          <chr> "aakash.r@stalkbuylove.com", "abhinav.a@stalkbuylove.com"
## $ agent.user.external_id    <lgl> NA, NA
## $ agent.user.fb_profile_id  <lgl> NA, NA
## $ agent.user.helpdesk_agent <lgl> TRUE, TRUE
## $ agent.user.id             <int> 1013512877, 1021869364
## $ agent.user.job_title      <chr> "", ""
## $ agent.user.language       <chr> "en", "en"
## $ agent.user.mobile         <lgl> NA, NA
## $ agent.user.name           <chr> "Aakash Rathore", "Abhinav Anand"
## $ agent.user.phone          <lgl> NA, NA
## $ agent.user.time_zone      <chr> "New Delhi", "New Delhi"
## $ agent.user.twitter_id     <lgl> NA, NA
## $ agent.user.updated_at     <chr> "2016-09-29T14:47:23+05:30", "2016-09-29T14:48:52+05:30"
```

Comment: Yes, that's what it looks like but that isn't what I need. I have been writing dataframes as CSV. How do I do it with this one?

Comment: I mean every object in this array of JSON objects has to be a row in CSV file